# Debezium error, schema isn't known to this connector

Tags: database, jboss-tools, debezium, apache-pulsar

I have a project using Debezium, mostly based on [this example](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/apache-pulsar), which is then connected to an Apache Pulsar.

I have changed a few configurations. The file now looks like this:

```
database.history=io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
offset.storage=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore
offset.storage.file.filename=offset.dat
offset.flush.interval.ms=5000
name=mysql-dbz-connector
database.hostname={ip}
database.port=3308
database.user={user}
database.password={pass}
database.dbname=database
database.server.name=test
table.whitelist=database.history_table,database.project_table
snapshot.mode=schema_only
schemas.enable=false        
include.schema.changes=false
pulsar.topic=persistent://public/default/{0}
pulsar.broker.address=pulsar://{ip}:6650
database.history=io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory
```

As you may understand, what I'm trying to do is to monitor the `history_table` and the `project_table` modifications from the database and then write payloads onto an Apache Pulsar.

My problem is as follows. In whatever snapshot mode I use, when an offset has been written, I can't restart the Debezium without getting an error on the next database update.

```
Encountered change event for table database.history_table whose schema isn't known to this connector
```

It only happens with an existing `offset.dat` file. I think this is because the schema is null within the `offset.dat` file. Take this one for example:

```
¨Ìsrjava.util.HashMap⁄¡√`—F
loadFactorI thresholdxp?@wur[B¨Û¯T‡xpG{"schema":null,"payload":["mysql-dbz-connector",{"server":"test"}]}uq~U{"ts_sec":1563802215,"file":"database-bin.000005","pos":79574,"server_id":1,"event":1}x
```

I first suspected the `schemas.enable=false` or the `include.schema.changes=false` parameters that I used to make the JSON more concise, but their values don't change anything in the `offset.dat` file.

Comment: I'm wondering if this could come from the database's binary logging configurations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in line `database.history=io.debezium.relational.history.MemoryDatabaseHistory`. The history will not survive restart. You should use FileDatabaseHistory instead of it.

Comment: I still have the same problem with these lines `database.history=io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory
database.history.file.filename=history.dat`. Weirdly enough, I don't have any "history.dat" created, though.

Comment: Have you noticed you have it twice in the config file?

Comment: Well, no, this is embarrassing. That fixed my problem, thanks !

Comment: Hey @JiriPechanec, I have a similar problem except that my db history is actually stored in a kafka topic via this option `"database.history.kafka.topic"`. And I also currently running into this "schema not known" error. I tried deleting+recreating the Debezium mysql connector, but it still throws this error. Do I need to delete and re-create the db history topic before re-creating the connector?